# Question about documenting project hours on PMP application

Tags: pmp

I've been working in a PMO since July of 2013. I estimate that I have roughly 3520 hours of project hours from working there. I got this estimate by counting 22 months between then and now and multiplied by 160 hours a month to get 3520 hours. At this pace, I estimate I would have 4500 hours in about 28 months. Do my projects need to span at least 36 months before I can take the test even though I would have the 4500 hours?

When I was in college I was a member of a business organization. We would report to a national headquarters. Each school year, we would have specific goals for things like recruiting new members and planning different types of events (professional development, community service, fundraising, etc.). We maintained a budget with somewhat defined and controlled record keeping. Each school year, we would report progress and results to headquarters and accumulate "points" depending on things like how many events we planned and executed and how many new members we recruited. Would I be able to consider these as "project hours" or am I only allowed to count paid work experience?

Answer (score 0):

Document project hours is about documenting the numbers of ours working professional on leading or directing a project, see the [PMP Handbook](http://www.pmi.org/certification/~/media/pdf/certifications/pdc_pmphandbook.ashx)

In this case, professional is not equal to getting paid. E.g. if you work for a charity organisation and manage projects voluntarily in a professional way, this counts also.

The important point is that you are able to assign your experience to one of the five process groups:

- Initiating
- Planning
- Execution
- Monitoring & Controlling
- Closing

You have to check, if your experience during your college time fits in this. If it is reasoned by education, it won't count to be professional.

Regarding your current 3520 hours: It is hard to believe that you had no times of sickness of holiday for the last 22 month. The important fact is, that you have to be able to name people (usually your customer, who could be your manager also) which may have to confirm the claimed hours.